# Setting manual X Values in Excel VBA for xlLineMarkers

Tags: vba, excel, graph, charts

I'm relatively new to using VBA within excel, but I'm trying to automatically generate graphs to track student's progress against target grades throughout the year.

The issue I'm having is plotting a line with just two points - their grade at the start of the year, and where they should be at the end of the year. I need this line to remain static whilst the progress at certain points throughout the year can be updated.

I've managed to create a graph like this manually in Excel, but I can't figure out how to to it with code. The graph should ideally look like this

*edit: I can't post images. The correct chart has a point at the first assessment, and the last assessment with a single line between the two*

However, the graphs I'm generating look more like this

*edit: can't post images. The issue with my graph is that the initial and final grade are only being plotted at the first two points and the rest of the range is blank.*

Here's the code I'm using

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""Progress"""
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='GradesForGraph'!$E$2:$V$2"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Worksheets("GradesForGraph").Range(ResultsRange)
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "=""Target"""
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = "={1,18}"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = Worksheets("GradesForGraph").Range(TargetRange)
```

The range 'TargetRange' refers to two cells in the sheet GradesForGraph with the student's initial grade and what their grade at the end of the year should be.

I've tried replacing "={1,18}" with an array of just the values 1,18 but to no avail (I'm using 1 and 18 as there are 18 assessment points throughout the year).

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using an XY scatter chart - or at least specifying that type for the second series?

Comment: Apologies - forgot to include that. I was using a line chart, but having now changed to a scatter chart has resolved the issue of my target grades not doing what I wanted - but I've lost my X-Axis labels (these were originally test names for the series progress)

Comment: Having just played about with it I think my issue lies in that data series 1 (progress) all have sequential string values on the X Axis (test names) - so I'm assuming I need to work a way around plotting my target points at the first and last point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an Excel Line Chart, every series uses the same X values. If you specify them for the first series, there is no need to specify them for the second. But this also means you will need that number of Y values to make a continuous target line. This means TargetRange needs 18 cells with the same target value.

Or you could add the target as an XY series. Use X values of Array(0.5, 18.5), so the line you draw will extend beyond the data points to the edges of the chart.

```
  With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .Name = "=""Progress"""
    .Values = Worksheets("GradesForGraph").Range(ResultsRange)
    .XValues = "='GradesForGraph'!$E$2:$V$2"
    .ChartType = xlLineMarkers
  End With
  With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .Name = "=""Target"""
    .Values = Worksheets("GradesForGraph").Range(TargetRange)
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
    .AxisGroup = xlPrimary
    .XValues = Array(0.5, 18.5)
  End With
```

Comment: Perfect - this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much!